# Hive -e and regex replace udf issue

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, udf, mapr

I am working on Hive 0.13 in MapR distro. I am seeing a weird issue when i run the following query in hive using the hive -e option.

Below is my query :

```
select regexp_replace('$60,825.48','\\$|\,','');
```

The above query works fine when I run from the hive shell directly and gives desired the output as **60825.48**.

Now, When I run the same **using the hive -e** as follows :

```
hive -e "select regexp_replace('$60,825.48','\\$|\,','');"
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 890 msec
OK
0825.48
Time taken: 7.813 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

The **"6"** gets trimmed off from the desired output.

Also, The same works fine with Hive -f option too.

Could you please help me identify the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
hive -e 'select regexp_replace("$60,825.48","\\$|\,","");'
```

If your objective is to remove everything except numbers and '.', then you can try this as well

```
hive -e 'select regexp_replace("$60,825.48","[^0-9.]","");'
```